Добавление генерируемых элементов на гренируемые листы 1с 8.22
Доброго времени суток!
Есть код:
Для инд = 2 По страниц Цикл         
        СтраницыФормы = Этаформа.ЭлементыФормы.ПанельМестаЗаказа.Страницы.Добавить(инд, инд, инд);
        ПолеРегистра = ЭлементыФормы.Добавить(Тип("Надпись"), "НадписьМесто" + Строка(инд), Истина, СтраницыФормы); 
        ПолеРегистра.Заголовок = "Что то там";
        ПолеРегистра.Ширина = 64;
        ПолеРегистра.Высота = 22;
КонецЦикла

Если вместо "СтраницыФормы" ставить "ПанельМестаЗаказа", то все появляться на первой вкладке, а нужно распределить элементы по создающимся вкладкам.
Причем Все это делается на "Панели" внутри которой есть "панель", где генерируются вкладки.
Используется 1с версии 8.22

Когда решил обратиться за помощью, то мозг решил подсказать решение))
ЭлементыФормы.ПанельМестаЗаказа.ТекущаяСтраница = ЭлементыФормы.ПанельМестаЗаказа.Страницы.Найти(инд);

